# Eureka Server and Spring Boot Admin in one Application

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I try to run Eureka Server and Spring Boot Admin Server in one Application (SBA Docu says this is possible). Eureka is working as intended but the Admin App still shows zero Applications.

Spring Boot Version 2.0.3, 
Spring Boot Admin Version 2.0.1

Eureka and SBA Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAdminServer
class KotlintestApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(KotlintestApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Server bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
      application:
        name: server
```

Server application.yml

```
spring:
  boot:
   admin:
     context-path: /admin

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/eureka
```

Client

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
class KotlintestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(KotlintestApplication::class.java, *args)
}

@Configuration
class SecurityPermitAllConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
    }
}
```

Client bootstrap.yml

```
 spring:
      application:
        name: client
 server:
    port: 0
```

Client application.yml

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    health-check-url-path: /actuator/health
    status-page-url-path: /actuator/info
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8080/eureka/
```

Comment: @EnableDiscoveryClient in SBA server is no longer required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer myself

Remove the `fetchRegistry: false` from the server application.yaml.
The Server has to fetch the registry to see the clients ...

Btw: You should set an instanceId if you want to run multiple instances with a random port on the same host. Otherwise SBA can't differ between the instances.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    instanceId : client-${random.uuid}
```